# Incompatible types while returning Either

Tags: java, either, vavr

I'm using vavr's `Either` to control flow of my application and it worked fine, until I didn't have to mix few domains...

First of all, I got one interface that is shared between domains.

```
public interface DomainError {
    String getCause();
}
```

And same for success, when I just want to inform user about that and don't need to return particular object.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class SuccessMessage {
    private final String message;
}
```

Now, each domain implements `DomainError` like this

```
public enum UserError implements DomainError {
    USERNAME_ALREADY_EXISTS("Username already exists"),
    INVALID_EMAIL("Provided email address is invalid");

    private final String cause;
    UserError(String cause) {
        this.cause = cause;
    }
    @Override
    public String getCause() {
        return cause;
    }
}
```

Similar it looks for `EmailError` which just have another values inside. Now, I have `EmailFacade`

```
public class EmailFacade {
    private final SendEmailUseCase sendEmail;
    private final CreateEmailUseCase createEmail;

    public Either<DomainError, SuccessMessage> sendUserVerificationEmail(UUID uuid, String receiver) {
        return sendEmail.send(createEmail.createUserVerificationEmail(uuid, receiver));
    }
}
```

And one of it's services returns

```
class SendEmailUseCase {
    Either<DomainError, SuccessMessage> send(EmailMessage message) {
        if(message == null) return Either.left(EmailError.EMPTY_MESSAGE);
        log.info(message.toString());
        return Either.right(new SuccessMessage("Email sent"));
    }
}
```

Now, I need to call this from my other domain, which handles registration of user.

In order to do that I wrote this method

```
Either<DomainError, SuccessMessage> register(RegisterUserDto registerUserDto) {
        if(userRepository.findUser(registerUserDto.getUsername()).isPresent())
            return Either.left(UserError.USERNAME_ALREADY_EXISTS);
        Either<DomainError, User> userCreationResult = User.createUser(registerUserDto);
        return userCreationResult
            .map(user -> {
                userRepository.save(user.toDto());
                final UUID uuid = verificationTokenRepository.generateVerificationToken(user.getUsername());
                return emailFacade.sendUserVerificationEmail(uuid, user.getUsername());
            });
    }
```

I'm doing few things here, but relevant part is last return statement, all above is working. `emailFacade.sendUserVerificationEmail()` returns `Either<DomainError, SuccessMessage>`, same as `register()` method. But for some reason, I'm getting this error

> Error:(28, 17) java: incompatible types: inference variable U has
>   incompatible bounds
>       equality constraints: com.johndoe.myapp.domain.SuccessMessage
>       lower bounds: `io.vavr.control.Either<com.johndoe.myapp.domain.DomainError,com.johndoe.myapp.domain.SuccessMessage>`

And I seriously can't understand what went wrong here...

Comment: Read the javadoc: https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/1.0.0-alpha-3/io/vavr/control/Either.html#map(java.util.function.Function). map() expects a function which transforms the right value into another right value. Not a function which transforms a right value into an Either. Reading the remaining of the javadoc should help you find out what you really need to call.

Answer (score 1):

Method `map` is used to transform value inside container. In your case it gives you value of User and expects that you return transformed value. So in case you are returning `Either<DomainError, User>` then type of result will be `Either<DomainError, Either<DomainError, User>>` and it is not what method signature expects as return type.

If you wan't to return Either from function, then you should use `flatMap` instead, which would flatten result to `Either<DomainError, User>`:

```
return userCreationResult
   .flatMap(user -> { //replace map with flatMap
        userRepository.save(user.toDto());
        final UUID uuid = verificationTokenRepository.generateVerificationToken(user.getUsername());
        return emailFacade.sendUserVerificationEmail(uuid, user.getUsername());
});
```